# is there any free solution to send mass mail on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008, sendmail

I have a server computer and installed Windows Server 2008 and IIS7. I need to send newsletter to 5000 customers. I want send everyday. But i don't configure mail account. I'm creating Gmail account. this only send 300 mail in per day. Another mail account same. 
I dont want any payable system.

My web technology is asp.net mvc 3.

Comment: It seems to me that your Windows Server could act as an SMTP server. Problem solved.

Comment: Which mail account configuring to SMTP server? Localhost is not working

Comment: The fact that you're asking this question means you don't know how to setup and maintain an smtp server. Once your clients all of a sudden won't receive your newsletter anymore, and you'll have to investigate on how to remove your server from all the blacklists, you'll find that any commercial mail system is worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure your own [SMTP server](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/751/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7/). You should be aware though that if you intend to send mass emails from your domain this domain could get blacklisted and commercial mail systems is worth the money.

Comment: how to create own smtp server?

Comment: @ebattulga, by installing the SMTP component on your server as shown in the tutorial I have linked to in my answer: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/751/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7/

Comment: SMTP server already installed. I'm configuring web SMTP mail, but following error shown `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25`

Comment: @ebattulga, well it seems that SMTP is not installed or it is not properly configured or simply not started.

Comment: Please see this. http://i662.photobucket.com/albums/uu346/ebattulga/smtpConfig.jpg

Comment: Yes, I see it. So is the SMTP server started?

Comment: How to know that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3763/discussion-between-ebattulga-and-darin-dimitrov)